# Splitting string based on list values into a list in Python

Tags: python, list, roman-numerals

At the moment I'm trying to create a new list from a string, based on matching values from another list. For example my list of values is:

```
['IX', 'C', 'D', 'XL', 'I', 'XC', 'M', 'L', 'CD', 'X', 'IV', 'CM']
```

Which are all Roman numerals. How would I go about taking a Roman numeral:

```
MMIX
```

and splitting it to:

```
['M', 'M', 'IX']
```

based on the previous list.

Any help would be great!

Comment: are you actually trying to convert the numeral? I dont know that this is the best way to do it.  I think its also to ambiguous as how would you parse "IXL" ?

Comment: You give a problem, then say help would be great, but what is your actual problem? What did you try? How didn't it work?

Comment: I dont think there is any way of doing it given the current problem statement ... too many reduce/reduce errors that will lead to ambiguous results

Comment: Here is a recipe for roman numerals to ints http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81611-roman-numerals/

Comment: assuming thats what he is actually after +1 :)

Comment: you have `X` and `C` in that list and you also have `XC`. So how is that even possible? There are 7 symbols in roman numeral system. do you want to break it to those?

Comment: I'm not fully trying to deal with roman numerals, simply split them into a the tokens in the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this approach will work in general to parse roman numerals.  For example, this code fails to properly parse `VIII` but that's because `V` isn't in the list of tokens.  But here's a simple recursive function that looks for one of the tokens at the beginning of the input string and assembles a list:

```
tokens = ['IX', 'C', 'D', 'XL', 'I', 'XC', 'M', 'L', 'CD', 'X', 'IV', 'CM']

def rn_split(numeral, results_so_far=[]):
    if len(numeral)==0:
        return results_so_far # Break the recursion
    for token in tokens:
        if numeral.startswith(token):
            results_so_far.append(token)
            recurse_numeral = numeral[ (len(token)): ]
            return rn_split(recurse_numeral, results_so_far)
    # Remainder of numeral didn't match.  Bail out
    results_so_far.append(numeral)
    return results_so_far
```